# PHP output to scrolling marquee

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

PHP script produces dynamic output, and print result on page into the div, here is example(php page):

```
<head>
  <title></title>
<script>
setInterval(function() {
    $('#reload').load('track.php');
}, 10000);
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="reload"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want show the output text in a scrolling marquee, with some styling applied. I know the marquee tag is deprecated, but this can be done using some javascript scroller. I searched for php and javascript combining but didn't find anything reliable. Can someone show the solution to solve this task?

Comment: The solution is simple: generate marquee content inside an element such as `<ul>`/`<li>` elements just the way you do in normal PHP. Then use a marquee script that accepts HTML markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check a jQuery plugin with a lot of features:

http://jscroller2.markusbordihn.de/example/image-scroller-windiv/

And this one is "silky smooth"

http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee

Try:

```
setInterval(function() { $('#reload').html(function() {$.get("http://espring.3eeweb.com/track.php", function(data){ return data; })}) }, 10000);​
```

Comment: It would be good to know how to adopt the second solution for my script.  I find the original code (my example above) does not work, the page does not show output. When call script track.php directly, it return results..

Comment: well I tried second link(jQuery Marquee script) with my code, not worked for me.

Comment: Can you post your code on jsfiddle? And I will try to help you.

Comment: here is: 
`<head>

<script>
setInterval(function() {
    $('#reload').load('track.php');
}, 10000);
</script>

<script src="jquery-1.2.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="gistfile1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(function () {
$('div.print marquee').marquee()
});
//-->
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="print">
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="2" width="300"><div id="reload"></div></marquee>
</div>

</body>
</html>`

Comment: Mate I tested your code with all major browsers(Chrome, IE9, Firefox) and it is working. Check. http://jsfiddle.net/4TdAX/

Comment: yes, I see. Though, it scroll 'Test' string, not actual php output.

Comment: Are you sure that your php is returning anything? Can you give my the actual url to your php file that is supposed to be printed inside the div?

Comment: two points I'm not sure: 1) the .load() method is jQuery's AJAX function and require link to jQuery library, which I did not specified in <head> section;
2) the script, seems, need be placed in the <body> section, not into the <head>, at least, this show examples at http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: yes put this in your head: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: your sample code works at jsfiddle.net/4TdAX, but canno get it work in my page.

Comment: It works now. I changed page extension to .html (I tested as php page). Note: should the _.load()_ script be placed in head or in body?

Comment: it doesn't matter. just place it in a `<script>` tag after including jquery. I believe it is also better to place in in a `document.ready` jquery function